# yii's 404 error page directs to custom default page

Tags: yii

i always get the default page, my default custom page, but it doesn't go to my 404 page... and main config is directing to site/error. And the below is my site/error. What else am I missing?

```
public function actionError()
    {
        $this->layout = '/layouts/main';
        $error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error->code;
        if(404==Yii::app()->errorHandler->error->code){
            $this->render('404');
        }
        else
            $this->render('error', array('error'=>$error));
    }
```

Comment: Does the control is being transferred to above mentioned function? do you want it this way? I am not sure about the term "default custom page". Do you mean that if statement is not being executed but else statement is?

Comment: not sure if i understand you correctly. But what im trying to do is just get the 404 error. If there is a 404 go to 404.php. If there are other errors go to error.php. So right now everything goes to my default, so all errors go there.

Comment: Did you change the errorAction in your config file? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#handling-errors-using-an-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function actionError() {
    $this->layout = '/layouts/main';
    $error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error;
    if($error['code'] == 404)
        $this->render('404');
    else
        $this->render('error', array('error'=>$error));
}
```

`Yii::app()->errorHandler->error` returns an array with details.. check documentation here..
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler#error-detail

Comment: it has to.. goto any controller action and write `throw new CHttpException(404, 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this action.');` and then goto that action, the 404 view will be rendered.. if it exists in site folder..